# How to convert JSON data into Hierarchical(tree) format using javascript/angularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

```
[
  {"id":1,"countryname":"India","zoneid":"1","countryid":"1","zonename":"South","stateid":"1","zid":"1","statename":"Karnataka"},
  {"id":1,"countryname":"India","zoneid":"1","countryid":"1","zonename":"South","stateid":"2","zid":"1","statename":"Karnataka"},
  {"id":1,"countryname":"India","zoneid":"1","countryid":"1","zonename":"South","stateid":"3","zid":"1","statename":"Karnataka"},
  {"id":1,"countryname":"India","zoneid":"2","countryid":"1","zonename":"East","stateid":"4","zid":"2","statename":"Karnataka"},
  {"id":2,"countryname":"UK","zoneid":"3","countryid":"2","zonename":"West","stateid":"5","zid":"3","statename":"Karnataka"},
  {"id":3,"countryname":"Australia","zoneid":"3","countryid":"3","zonename":"West","stateid":"6","zid":"3","statename":"Karnataka"},
  {"id":3,"countryname":"Australia","zoneid":"4","countryid":"3","zonename":"North","stateid":"7","zid":"4","statename":"Karnataka"},
  {"id":4,"countryname":"Sweedan","zoneid":null,"countryid":null,"zonename":null}
       ]
```

Comment: please brief you question....rather  than posting only a json

Comment: There is no context here? How are you trying to achieve the hierachy? There is a list of objects in the array already so theoretically, its already achieved?

Comment: @Karthik Please clarify: Are you going to convert json data to another format or to build a user-interface that can display json data in tree format?

Comment: By using javascript we have to convert this format to                                              { folders: [
      { name: 'India', folders: [
         { name: 'South', folders: [
               { name: 'Karnataka', folders: [
                     { name: 'Bangalore', files: [
                              { name: 'JP Nagar' }, 
                              { name: 'Jaynagar' }]}]

               },{ name: 'Kerala' },
               { name: 'Tamil Nadu' },
               { name: 'Andra' }] },

         { name: 'East' },
         { name: 'West' }
      ]},

Comment: http://jimliu.github.io/angular-ui-tree/ please chk this link u will see tree structure code to ur right.

Comment: @gm2008 : Yes we want to convert json data into tree format

Comment: @StevenBrookes : Yes steve i have json data. i want to convert above json data into tree format(like angularjs tree view)

Comment: @NidhishKrishnan : yes, i want to convert above json data into tree format(like angularjs tree view format)

Answer (score 0):

Using JSON.parse(your json string)

go to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

`angular.fromJson(string)` and `angular.toJson(object/array)`

Answer (score 0):

you would need to normalize your data so that related records for a country reside under a child collection like so:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "countryname": "India",
    "zones": [
        {
            "zoneid": 1,
            "zonename": "South",
            "states": [
                {
                    "stateid": 1,
                    "statename": "Karnataka"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "zoneid": 2,
            "zonename": "East",
            "states": [
                {
                    "stateid": 1,
                    "statename": "Karnataka"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "countryname": "UK",
    "zones": [
        {
            "zoneid": "3",
            "zonename": "West",
            "states": [
                {
                    "stateid": "5",
                    "statename": "Karnataka"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

if your data is a string, you will need to convert it to JSON via JSON.parse, as previous answers have described. From there (if you can't normalize your data on the server side), you can access the properties to build your normalized JSON like a normal object. There are a few ways of building the 'new' JSON array, but hopefully this is a starting point for you. If you are still having issues I could point you in the direction of ways of doing it.